# azure blob download task issue

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

While creating SSIS package with the azure blob download task, the files can be downloaded from Azure blob to my local machine. The SSIS execution is fine but once I deploy the package in SSISDB( In Azure Sql DB), the Azure blob download task fails as it is unable to access the local folder.

[image: The task details is mentioned here]

The task can't be run in the SSMS ( in Azure). the error showing as the local path can't be accessed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions here are expected to show research effort, that is, what *you've* already done to solve your problem. We're happy to help, but only after you've tried yourself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please consider to join your Azure-SSIS IR to a Virtual Network (VNet) connected to your on-premises network, see [Join Azure-SSIS IR to a VNet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/join-azure-ssis-integration-runtime-virtual-network). This way you can provide a file share on-premises as a "local directory" on the Azure Blob Download Task.

To access a file share on premises from packages running in Azure, do the following things:

1. Allow access through Windows firewall.
2. Join your Azure-SSIS IR to a VNet that is connected to the file share on premises.
3. Use SSISDB catalog.set_execution_credential stored procedure to provide
   credentials.